# Video playback very white contrast with multiple video players

Tags: video, graphics-card, media-player, brightness, contrast

So here is the deal, all my video players, EXCEPT winamp, are displaying the video with a very white contrast. I have the community combined codec pack installed, I have tried reinstalling the codecs and reinstalling the players. Not sure why winamp works, but since winamp has problems with aero and full screen, I need my other players to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be related to the graphic card video settings, some of them come with an option to adjust videos brightness/contrast, check out.

Comment: Those other players may be showing more realisitically the contrast of being outside like that, but the Winamp player is showing the actual way the show depicts it.

Comment: Nope, if you keep watching a go inside of the school, you can see that the faces are under a white fuzz, sorry but thats not normal. Maybe my screenshot wasnt the best one, being outside... Take alook again http://dl.dropbox.com/u/643924/Untitled.png

Comment: yes, right, my screen was on high contrast. but i can see that winamp is using "Nullsoft DirectShow Decoder" (his own decoder) this make him independent from the codec other players are using. it may be related to the graphic card video settings, some of them come with an option to adjust videos brightness/contrast, check out.

Comment: Hi, yep, now I remembering changing my nvidia settings. Thanks! Can you edit your question so that I can give you a +1? Thanks~